# I can't launch 2 of my games on steam. One game I have 77 hours playing then it stopped launching out of the blue

Tags: games, steam

It just started a few days ago. I've been playing Grid Autosport for a month now and it just up and stopped launching. I thought it was a game issue but, now I'm thinking it's a steam issue. I just bought Mad Max last night and it to will not launch. I hit play and it gives me the "preparing to launch" box then it goes back to play.
 Here is the error log.
I'm using Ubuntu Mate 18.04.4
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.3.0-42-generic
Shell: bash 4.4.20
DE: MATE 1.20.0
WM: Metacity (Marco)
CPU: AMD Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega Graphics @ 4x 3.6GHz [40.1°C]
GPU: GeForce GTX 1650 SUPER
RAM: 1470MiB / 15935MiB

```
[0325/134149.550531:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(8543)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_ENUM : glFramebufferTexture2D: <- error from previous GL command
Loaded Config for Local Override Path for App ID 255220, Controller 0: /home/scott/.steam//controller_base/empty.vdf
GameAction [AppID 255220, ActionID 3] : LaunchApp changed task to ProcessingInstallScript with ""
GameAction [AppID 255220, ActionID 3] : LaunchApp changed task to SynchronizingCloud with ""
GameAction [AppID 255220, ActionID 3] : LaunchApp changed task to SiteLicenseSeatCheckout with ""
GameAction [AppID 255220, ActionID 3] : LaunchApp changed task to CreatingProcess with ""
GameAction [AppID 255220, ActionID 3] : LaunchApp waiting for user response to CreatingProcess ""
GameAction [AppID 255220, ActionID 3] : LaunchApp continues with user response "CreatingProcess"
Game update: AppID 255220 "", ProcID 6307, IP 0.0.0.0:0
Starting app 255220
Loaded Config for Local Override Path for App ID 255220, Controller 0: /home/scott/.steam//controller_base/empty.vdf
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/scott/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Adding process 6307 for game ID 255220
GameAction [AppID 255220, ActionID 3] : LaunchApp changed task to WaitingGameWindow with ""
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/scott/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
pid 6310 != 6309, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/scott/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
GameAction [AppID 255220, ActionID 3] : LaunchApp changed task to Completed with ""
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/scott/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
 Adding process 6308 for game ID 255220
Adding process 6309 for game ID 255220
 Adding process 6311 for game ID 255220
 Adding process 6312 for game ID 255220
Game update: AppID 255220 "", ProcID 6312, IP 0.0.0.0:0
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): SteamUser018 / User
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): SteamFriends015 / Friends
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): SteamUtils007 / Utils
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): SteamMatchMaking009 / Matchmaking
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): SteamMatchMakingServers002 / MatchmakingServers
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): STEAMUSERSTATS_INTERFACE_VERSION011 / UserStats
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): STEAMAPPS_INTERFACE_VERSION007 / Apps
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): SteamNetworking005 / Networking
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): STEAMREMOTESTORAGE_INTERFACE_VERSION013 / RemoteStorage
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): STEAMSCREENSHOTS_INTERFACE_VERSION002 / Screenshots
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): STEAMHTTP_INTERFACE_VERSION002 / HTTP
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): STEAMUNIFIEDMESSAGES_INTERFACE_VERSION001 / UnifiedMessages
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): SteamController003 / Controller
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): STEAMUGC_INTERFACE_VERSION007 / UGC
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): STEAMAPPLIST_INTERFACE_VERSION001 / AppList
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): STEAMMUSIC_INTERFACE_VERSION001 / Music
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): STEAMMUSICREMOTE_INTERFACE_VERSION001 / MusicRemote
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): STEAMHTMLSURFACE_INTERFACE_VERSION_003 / HTMLSurface
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): STEAMINVENTORY_INTERFACE_V001 / Inventory
RecordSteamInterfaceCreation (PID 6312): STEAMVIDEO_INTERFACE_V001 / Video
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 255220
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198281400238 [API loaded no]
/home/scott/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/GRID Autosport/bin/GridAutosport: symbol lookup error: /home/scott/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: SDL_RWseek
Game removed: AppID 255220 "", ProcID 6312 
Game 255220 created interface STEAMAPPLIST_INTERFACE_VERSION001 / AppList
Game 255220 created interface STEAMAPPS_INTERFACE_VERSION007 / Apps
Game 255220 created interface STEAMHTMLSURFACE_INTERFACE_VERSION_003 / HTMLSurface
Game 255220 created interface STEAMHTTP_INTERFACE_VERSION002 / HTTP
Game 255220 created interface STEAMINVENTORY_INTERFACE_V001 / Inventory
Game 255220 created interface STEAMMUSICREMOTE_INTERFACE_VERSION001 / MusicRemote
Game 255220 created interface STEAMMUSIC_INTERFACE_VERSION001 / Music
Game 255220 created interface STEAMREMOTESTORAGE_INTERFACE_VERSION013 / RemoteStorage
Game 255220 created interface STEAMSCREENSHOTS_INTERFACE_VERSION002 / Screenshots
Game 255220 created interface STEAMUGC_INTERFACE_VERSION007 / UGC
Game 255220 created interface STEAMUNIFIEDMESSAGES_INTERFACE_VERSION001 / UnifiedMessages
Game 255220 created interface STEAMUSERSTATS_INTERFACE_VERSION011 / UserStats
Game 255220 created interface STEAMVIDEO_INTERFACE_V001 / Video
Game 255220 created interface SteamController003 / Controller
Game 255220 created interface SteamFriends015 / Friends
Game 255220 created interface SteamMatchMaking009 / Matchmaking
Game 255220 created interface SteamMatchMakingServers002 / MatchmakingServers
Game 255220 created interface SteamNetworking005 / Networking
Game 255220 created interface SteamUser018 / User
Game 255220 created interface SteamUtils007 / Utils
Game 255220 method call count for IClientUser::BIsSubscribedApp : 1
Game 255220 method call count for IClientUser::GetUserDataFolder : 1
Game 255220 method call count for IClientUser::GetSteamID : 2
Game 255220 method call count for IClientUtils::GetAppID : 21
Game 255220 method call count for IClientUtils::RecordSteamInterfaceCreation : 20
Game 255220 method call count for IClientAppManager::BIsDlcEnabled : 1
Game 255220 method call count for IClientAppManager::GetCurrentLanguage : 1
Uploaded AppInterfaceStats to Steam
Exiting app 255220
No cached sticky mapping in ActivateActionSet.No cached sticky mapping in ActivateActionSet.
```

Comment: What version and flavor of Unbuntu do you have?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Looks like you're missing a symbol the game thinks is in /home/scott/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: SDL_RWseek

Maybe try 'sudo apt install libsdl2-*'

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!! That did it! I can't say thank you enough!

Comment: How do I mark this a solved?